# Another PHP XML parsing error: "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding!"

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

Error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 3: parser error : Input
>   is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding
>   ! Bytes: 0xE7 0x61 0x69 0x73

XML from database (output from view source in FF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><audit><audit_detail>
    <fieldname>role_fra</fieldname>
    <old_value>Role en fran&#xe7;ais</old_value>
    <new_value>Role &#xe7; en fran&#xe7;ais</new_value>
</audit_detail></audit></xml>
```

If I understand correctly, the error is related to the first ç encoded in the old_value tag. To be precise, the error is related to this based on the bytes: "çais" ?

Here's how I load the XML:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($ed['updates'][$i]['audit_data']);
```

The I loop through using this:

```
foreach ($xmlData->audit_detail as $a){
//code here
}
```

The field in the database is of data type text and is set utf8_general_ci.

My function to create the audit_detail stubs:

```
function ed_audit_node($field, $new, $old){


    $old = htmlentities($old, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $new = htmlentities($new, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    $out = <<<EOF
        <audit_detail>
            <fieldname>{$field}</fieldname>
            <old_value>{$old}</old_value>
            <new_value>{$new}</new_value>
        </audit_detail>
EOF;
    return $out;
}
```

The insert in the database is done like this:

```
function ed_audit_insert($ed, $xml){
    global $visitor;

    $sql = <<<EOF
    INSERT INTO ed.audit
    (employee_id, audit_date, audit_action, audit_data, user_id) 
    VALUES (
        {$ed[emp][employee_id]}, 
        now(), 
        '{$ed[audit_action]}', 
        '{$xml}', 
        {$visitor[user_id]}
    );      
EOF;
    $req = mysql_query($sql,$ed['db']) or die(db_query_error($sql,mysql_error(),__FUNCTION__));

}
```

The weirdest part is that the following works (without the xml declaration though) in a simple PHP file:

```
$testxml = <<<EOF
<audit><audit_detail>
        <fieldname>role_fra</fieldname>
        <old_value>Role en fran&#xe7;ais</old_value>
        <new_value>Role &#xe7; en fran&#xe7;ais</new_value>
    </audit_detail></audit>
EOF;
```

$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($testxml);

Can someone help shed some light on this?

**Edit #1** - I'm now using DOM to build the XML document and have gotten rid of the error. Function here:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('audit'));
$xmlCount = 0;

if($role_fra != $curr['role']['role_fra']){
   $root->appendChild(ed_audit_node($dom, 'role_fra', $role_fra, $curr['role']['role_fra'])); 
   $xmlCount++;
}

...

function ed_audit_node($dom, $field, $new, $old){

    //create audit_detail node
    $ad = $dom->createElement('audit_detail');

    $fn = $dom->createElement('fieldname');
    $fn->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($field));
    $ad->appendChild($fn);

    $ov = $dom->createElement('old_value');
    $ov->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($old));
    $ad->appendChild($ov);

    $nv = $dom->createElement('new_value');
    $nv->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($new));
    $ad->appendChild($nv);

    //append to document
    return $ad;
}

if($xmlCount != 0){
    ed_audit_insert($ed,$dom->saveXML());   
}
```

However, I think I now have a display problem as this text "Roééleç sé en franêais" (new_value) is being displayed as:

display problem:
[image]

In my HTML document, I have the following declaration for content-type (unfortunately, I don't hold the keys to make changes here):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I've tried iconv() to convert to ISO-8859-1, however, most of the special characters are being removed when doing the conversion. All that remains is "Ro" using this command:

```
iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1',$node->new_value);
```

iconv output:
[image]

The field in the db is: utf8_general_ci. However, the connection charset would be whatever is the default.

Not quite sure where to go from here...

**Edit #2** - I tried utf8_decode to see if that wouldn't help, but it didn't.

```
utf8_decode($a->new_value);
```

Output:
[image]

I also noticed that my field in the db did contain UTF-8. Which is good.

Comment: What is the column encoding in the database where you store the xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `&#xe7;` is "ç", then your encoding is Windows-1252 (or maybe ISO-8859-1), but not UTF-8.

Comment: DOH! I did get those values translated on the ISO-8859-1 char table... sigh. Then that means that I'm not getting UTF-8 returned from the database then. What would be the best way to do this without having to go in a config file? I read about set names 'utf-8'. However, my select statement would fail whenever I had that in...

Comment: @Tekius: You are currently using string concatenation (a PHP heredoc) to build your XML. Don't do that. Use a DOM to build your XML. May be a few more lines of code, but you won't get into character encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that seems to have gotten rid of the error. However, see my edits as I'm now having display issues of these special characters. I've tried a few things but the issue is still unresolved. Thanks!

Comment: @Tekius: I'm afraid character encoding problems between MySQL and PHP are not my field of expertise. Maybe you could make a new question describing the problem in more detail and reduce this one to its original form, so the new problem gets some attention. I would probably start with checking what the database actually stores (select character codes of single characters) and if that's proper UTF-8. Then check what PHP receives (char codes again). Then check if that's consistent with the Content-Type header. Then what the browser receives (via FireBug or WireShark).