# SOAP UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, soap, encoding, utf-8

I have a strange problem. In `PHP` I want to communicate to a Web Service with SOAP.

```
$soapURL = "http://www.somedomain.com/xyz.asmx?WSDL";
$soapParameters = Array('login' => "123", 'password' => "pwd", 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'exceptions' => True) ;
$client = new SoapClient($soapURL, $soapParameters);
```

With XAMPP it works locally without problems.

When I try it on my web server, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.somedomain.com/xyz.asmx?WSDL' : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xFC 0x6C 0x74 0x69 in ...
```

The error raises at the last line of my code example.

Any Ideas?

- `mb_detect_encoding($soapURL);` says the String is of format ASCII
- I tried to convert every string to UTF-8 with `utf8_encode`, `iconv` and mb_convert_encoding...
- first line of php file is: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: check the file encoding for your file.php

Comment: I don't know how. I simply pushed the files with FTP to the server. The server only has a webinterface. When I edit the php File, the Web-Editor sayd the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: download the file and look at its properties using a good editor. I use Zend Studio, but notepad++, or gedit on linux I think can tell you what is the encoding of the file and even let you change it.

Comment: thanks, but the editor says the the file is UTF-8 encoded

Comment: now you know is not this the issue. Start looking at the contents of what is coming, probably is something not properly encoded in the content.

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662008/another-php-xml-parsing-error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was the communication from Windows server and Linux client. I don't know why it works on some Linux machines, but never mind.

I added a local wsdl file at the source and use that for the SOAPClient. For the server I used the __setLocation function.